# Having issue with adding product through PHP code in STRIPE Payment

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

**I am trying to add payment in my stripe account through api but i am getting this error **

### Notice: Undefined property: Stripe\Service\CoreServiceFactory::$price in C:\xampp\htdocs\sentemail\stripe-php-7.88.0\lib\Service\AbstractServiceFactory.php on line 55 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\sentemail\price.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sentemail\price.php on line 10

**AND THIS IS MY CODE PLEASE HELP ME TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE**

```
<?php  ini_set("display_errors", 1); require 'stripe-php-7.88.0/init.php';


$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(   'pk_test_mykey' );

$stripe->price->create([  "id" => "pi_1Dor642eZvKYlo2C96OeaLE3",   "object"=> "payment_intent",   'price' => 'price_1JCMCeLGVxlfB4ARCzBODYPv',   'currency' => 'usd',   'payment_method_types' => ['payment'],
    'name' =>"Hamza",

]);
```

Comment: i cannot add product in stripe product using php apis

Answer (score 1):

According to the Stripe documentation (section "prices") you should use

`$stripe->prices->create([...]);` not `$stripe->price->create([...]);`.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create?lang=php

Comment: there was issue with price I have to enter prices instead of price